# UIImages created from NSData not honoring UIViewContentMode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I have been dealing with this problem by working around it for quite some time, but I really would like to know the correct way of handling the situation:

If I get an image as NSData from CoreData like so:

```
NSData *myImageData = myEntity.Image;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:myImageData];
[cell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

If the image is larger than the UIImageView's CGRect, the image does not constrain itself to the CGRect of the UIImageView.

What I currently do to work around the issue using code that is something like:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(98, 98);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

cell.imageView.image = scaledImage;
```

Which works, but I would certainly like someone to tell me what I am doing wrong with the ContentMode approach as it is supposed to work.

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Not sure if this has any impact on the scenario, but I am trying to do this from within a UITableViewCell

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to either call `[cell.imageView setNeedsDisplay]` after you set the content mode, or move the call the `setContentMode` to before you set the `cell.imageView.image` value.

Comment: Tried both of those...no luck.

Comment: Then I suspect there is more going on with your code than you posted, that is, it is a broader problem. You might try positing more code.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I have written a standalone example to try to recreate the issue.  I have found that the issue may be related to the image itself.  I am still doing some work to recreate the problem, but it does seem that the image works in some cases and not in others.